# Tkinter radio buttons aren't checked by default

Tags: python, tkinter

I am at a loss. My radio buttons won't check by default, even though I have followed various tutorials for radio buttons. Not sure what I am doing wrong, I am setting the default radio button to the False button.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import *


class ExampleView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        """ create StringVars for our shape fill radio button group """
        shape_fill_status = tk.StringVar()

        """ create radio button group for turning off shape fill """
        shape_fill_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        shape_fill_label = tk.Label(shape_fill_frame, text="Fill Shape: ",  anchor="w")
        shape_fill_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx = 10)
        shape_fill_false = tk.Radiobutton(shape_fill_frame, text = "False", variable = shape_fill_status, value = 0)

        shape_fill_true = tk.Radiobutton(shape_fill_frame, text = "True", variable = shape_fill_status, value = 1)
        shape_fill_status.set(0)
        shape_fill_false.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx = 10)
        shape_fill_true.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx = 10)
        shape_fill_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, stick="w")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    view = ExampleView(root)
    view.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x200")
    root.mainloop()
```

And here is what my tkinter widget looks like:

[image: screenshot of widget]

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with one or more radiobuttons, we really only need enough code to show a couple of radiobuttons. We don't need to see all of the other widgets and code.

Comment: I edited it to meet the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable standard.

Comment: Since "FIll Shape" has a boolean value, I think it would be better represented as a **single** on/off type `Radiobutton` because its two possible values are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @martineau: from a traditional ux perspective, if you use a single widget it should be a checkbutton rather than a radiobutton. Checkbuttons are on/off, radiobuttons are for one-of-many choices. I agree that in this particular case with just a single true/false value, a checkbutton seems like the wiser choice.

Comment: <slapping hand on forehead> @Bryan: Yeah, yeah, that's what I meant to say. `;¬)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a local variable to store the `StringVar`. Once `__init__` finishes, the variables get destroyed.

Change `shape_fill_status` to `self.shape_fill_status` everywhere.